# "print" style to string conversion in R

Tags: r, string

When I print certain objects, they are printed in a nice visual format in the console. For instance `wilcox.test` returns a list type of class "htest". If I print it I get this:

```
    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  TRACK_MEAN_SPEED by 1
W = 5540, p-value = 0.0000037
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

When I use `toString(wilcox.test(...))`, I get this:

```
[1] "c(W = 5540), NULL, 0.00000369974145369964, c(`location shift` = 0), two.sided, Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction, TRACK_MEAN_SPEED by 1"
```

I have also tried to get print output:

```
printOutput = print(wilcox.test(...))
```

, which returns the object itself.

I wonder if there is any way to convert objects like `print` would print them, **without capturing console output**?

Comment: One way is to read the code by running `getAnywhere('print.htest')`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas not solving the problem in general but it solves the one with htest or each individual class.

Comment: Use `?capture.output` or `?sink`. There's no general way to do this for all functions otherwise. Is this question specifically about `wilcox.test`? Each custom print function is free to do whatever it likes. And most of them dump directly to the console without creating intermediate string values somewhere.

Comment: There's no way to get objects like this without capturing the console output. You may still capture the individual elements from the result and write your own method. It's one of the way how the broom package works e.g. `broom::tidy(wilcox.test(rnorm(10)))`

Comment: @MrFlick supposed to be for any function but I see now that it is by logic/design impossible. Probably to allow really long prints to not run into issues with memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using `utils::capture.output`, which comes with `R`.

```r
a_wilcox_test <- wilcox.test(rnorm(10))
get_print_invisibly <- function(x) invisible(capture.output(print(x)))

printed_stuff <- get_print_invisibly(a_wilcox_test)

print(printed_stuff) #doesn't work
#> [1] ""                                                       
#> [2] "\tWilcoxon signed rank test"                             
#> [3] ""                                                       
#> [4] "data:  rnorm(10)"                                       
#> [5] "V = 21, p-value = 0.5566"                               
#> [6] "alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0"
#> [7] ""
cat(printed_stuff, sep = '\n')
#> 
#>  Wilcoxon signed rank test
#> 
#> data:  rnorm(10)
#> V = 21, p-value = 0.5566
#> alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
a_wilcox_test
#> 
#>  Wilcoxon signed rank test
#> 
#> data:  rnorm(10)
#> V = 21, p-value = 0.5566
#> alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>